# Can Paypal be used to sell both physical and digital goods?

Tags: paypal

The question is in the title. After spending few hours googling the issue, I am still not clear on this.

My client has a shop where she sells both physical and digital goods. Can I use Paypal shopping cart to sell both (with one checkout); where a download would be presented for the customer after payment and physical goods shipped as per usual? And the customer would pay once.

Comment: Not really a programming/API question, is it?

Comment: I don't know. I just need it answered. If it turns out not api related, then I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need something to trigger the digital goods though, something like the IPN api should work: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Basically you will need a file to read the response from Paypal, determine if/what digital good was sold and generate a response.

Comment: So basically extra php coding will be required (paypal api)? thank you. And just to confirm - this will allow the customer to pay once for all cart contents(physical and digital)?

Comment: another thing that I am concerned with: I would like to provide a download link...so according to your answer I need to do it myself, meaning i have to white code that produces expiring links/secure links(since I don't want people to snoop on my server)...I was under the impression that Paypal cart will already do all that.

Comment: Yes you will need something server side to read the response from Paypal (and verify it), you can pass item information to Paypal so digital and physical goods are okay. As far as I know Paypal does not have a digital goods module that can handle creating secure links. Maybe take a look at http://www.e-junkie.com/?